# Getting a segmentation fault. Can't figure out why

Tags: c, linux, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm making a phonebook program with a binary search tree. Whenever I try to input a new data, the segmentation fault occurs. First, I have type definition structure which name is `phoneData.`

```
typedef struct phoneData {
    char name[NAME_LEN];
    char phoneNum[PHONE_LEN];
    struct phoneData *right, *left;
} phoneData;

void InputPhoneData()
{   //phoneData *pData;
    char name[NAME_LEN];
    char phoneNum[PHONE_LEN];

    /*if ((pData = (phoneData*)malloc(sizeof(phoneData))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory Allocation failed\n");
        return;
      }*/

    fputs("이름 입력: ", stdout);
    if (fgetString(name, NAME_LEN, stdin) == 1) {
        getchar();
        return;
    }

    fputs("전화번호 입력: ", stdout);
    if (fgetString(phoneNum, PHONE_LEN, stdin) == 1) {
        getchar();
        return;
    }

    insert_node(name, phoneNum);
    numOfData++;

    fputs("입력이 완료되었습니다.", stdout);
    getchar();
}
```

And this is the function which I call to input a data. Please don't mind the Korean sentences. In the function, I call another function  `insert_node`. This is the function which inserts the binary search tree node.

```
void insert_node(char name[], char phoneNum[])
{
    phoneData *p, *t;
    phoneData *n;

    t = *root;
    p = NULL;

    while (t != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(name, t->name) == 0) 
            return;

        p = t;
        if (strcmp(name, p->name) < 0)
            t = p->left;
        else
            t = p->right;
    }

    n = (phoneData*)malloc(sizeof(phoneData));
    if (n == NULL)
        return;

    strcpy(n->name, name);
    strcpy(n->phoneNum, phoneNum);
    n->left = n->right = NULL;

    if (p != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(p->name, name) < 0)
            p->left = n;
        else
            p->right = n;
    }
    else
        *root = n;
}
```

I'm still wondering which is the part that I'm getting a segmentation fault. I already checked the `fgetString` function, and it seems to be okay. Did I make any mistakes on `InputPhoneData` function or `insert_node` function?

Comment: Have you tried valgrind? It might show you on which line is the problem.

Comment: You set `t = *root;`; where is `root` initialised? (and defined for that matter)

Comment: And by the way, the variable 'root' is a global variable which is a double pointer initialized as NULL. (phoneData **root = NULL;)

Comment: So, it starts as `NULL` and you derefrence it when you try to add things - this might be the cause of the segfault.

Comment: What is `fgetString()`?

Comment: Are you trying to implement binary tree using phoneData?

Comment: fgetString is a function that I made. It looks like the one below.

Comment: int fgetString(char *buf, int maxLen, FILE *fp)
{
        int i;
        char ch;

        for (i = 0; i < maxLen; i++)
        {
//              ch = getchar();
                ch = fgetc(fp);

                if (ch == '\n')
                {
                        buf[i] = '\0';
                        return 0;
                }
                buf[i] = ch;
        }

        puts("입력이 너무 깁니다.");
        printf("최대 입력 길이는 %d bytes입니다.", maxLen - 1);
        clear_inputBuffer();
        return 1;
}

Comment: @HabiSheriff Yes, I'm implementing a binary search tree with a phoneData!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And by the way, the variable 'root' is a global variable which is a double pointer initialized as NULL. (phoneData **root = NULL;)

That's your problem right there. `*root` will dereference a NULL pointer.

Change the declaration to:

```
phoneData *root = NULL;
```

and replace `*root` with `root` and `root` with `&root` in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easy, fun and interesting to debug such kind of issues.
Try to debug using gdb :)

You can check following link,
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb